# Angular routes and views and controllers

Tags: angularjs, controller, routes, view, angularjs-scope

I am trying to make a very simple app with routes and views, that displays a test text changing into "click" when a button is clicked.

I have an index.html file with an ng-view thats calls properly a test.html view. This view is supposed to use a testCtrl.js with a simple model.

But when it loads, the view seems to be called, but there is a problem with the scope, or the controller. When I click on a button the word test is supposed to become "click" but nothing happens.

here is the index.html

```
    <body ng-app="simtoolbelt">
    <div ng-view></div>



<script src="js/modules/angular-route.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/controllers/testCtrl.js"></script>
<script src="js/vendor/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="js/foundation.min.js"></script>
<script>
  $(document).foundation();
</script>
```

here is the app.js handling the routes and views:

```
    var simtoolbelt = angular.module('simtoolbelt', ['ngRoute']);

    simtoolbelt.config(['$routeProvider',
      function($routeProvider) {
      $routeProvider.
          when('/test', {
            templateUrl: 'views/test.html',
            controller: 'testCtrl'
          }).
          otherwise({
             redirectTo: '/test'
          });
    }]);
```

The test controller:

```
    simtoolbelt.controller('testCtrl', ['$scope', function($scope){

  $scope.test = "test";
  $scope.change = function($scope){
    $scope.test = "Click";
  };

   }]);
```

And finally the test view:

```
    <div ng-controller="testCtrl">
      <h1 ng-model="test">Le {{test}} fonctionne</h1>
      <button ng-click="change()">Click</button>
    </div>
```

All of that is in a localhost, and I really have no clue of what it is I am mising... Thanks  lot guys for any help you can give me !

Answer (score 0):

Your function "change" takes the argument "$scope". In `ng-click` you call a method without arguments.

Remove the parameter from your `change` method:

```
$scope.change = function(){
 $scope.test = "Click";
};
```

Furthermore, there is no need for the `ng-model` attribute in your `h1` tag.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But it still won't work... I did as you told me, I removed the scope parameter from the function, but still.

Comment: Have you read the second part of the answer? ng-model is only used for bi-directional data binding (in input, select elements).

Comment: I skipped it, and you were right, that was the problem !! Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 0):

Try to change controller definition in your routing to "only controller name" like

```
simtoolbelt.config(['$routeProvider',
  function($routeProvider) {
  $routeProvider.
      when('/test', {
        templateUrl: 'views/test.html',
        controller: 'testCtrl'
      }).
      otherwise({
         redirectTo: '/test'
      });
}]);
```

I have not test it yet but it should work.

Comment: Ok, I figured it out. It didn't work because of the "ng-model" attribute. Once I removed it that worked properly. So I used <h1> Le {{test}} fonctionne <h1> instead of <h1 ng-model = "test"> Le {{ test }} fonctionne <h1>